# Add target properties to an existing imported library in CMake

Tags: cmake

External project is built by CMake and installed in a directory visible via `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`. As it's CMake project, it installs proper `.cmake` files. In those, automatically generated, files an `EXPORTED` target is created and all required properties are set.

What I would like to do, is - without modification of original `CMakeLists.txt` - add a compile definition, that I need in order to properly include header from this library.

So far I've tried two approaches:

**Re-add library and specify definitions normally**

```
add_library(_external_lib_name_ INTERFACE IMPORTED)
target_compile_definitions(_external_lib_name_ INTERFACE FOO_BAR)
```

This doesn't work, as all the already set properties of the target (like include directories) are ignored.

**Just add definitions**

```
target_compile_definitions(_external_lib_name_ INTERFACE FOO_BAR)
```

This time CMake complains:

```
CMake Error at foo.cmake:1 (target_compile_definitions):
  Cannot specify compile definitions for target "_external_lib_name_" which is not built by this project.
```

Currently I am thinking about a proxy target:

```
add_library(_proxy_target_ INTERFACE)
target_link_libraries(_proxy_target_ INTERFACE _external_lib_name_)
target_compile_definitions(_proxy_target_ INTERFACE FOO_BAR)
```

While this one might work, does anyone know if there is a better way of modifying imported targets?

**Update**:

Using Tsyvarev's answer I was able to make it work, but there is another issue: in order for the target to be properly modified, I need to `include` a file that first `find_package` and later `set_property`. If I don't use `include`, but standard `CMakeLists.txt` and a `add_subdirectory` the target holds old properties.

Answer (score 4):

Command `target_compile_definitions` with *INTERFACE* keyword appends to property [INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS.html) but doesn't work with *IMPORTED* targets. You need to use a command which directly works with the target properties:

```
set_property(TARGET _external_lib_name_ APPEND PROPERTY INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS FOO_BAR)
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Sadly there is nothing in the docs about it (why manual property setting works, but not `target_*` commands).

Comment: Hm, interesting: [older target_compile_definitions documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/command/target_compile_definitions.html) notes that the command is inapplicable for  *IMPORTED* targets, but the [newer one](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/command/target_compile_definitions.html) notes about ALIAS targets instead. Probably, things has been changed while CMake evolves.